# Dual booting ubuntu and windows7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have ubuntu in my laptop and i have to dual boot it with windows 7. Can anyone help me how to dual boot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list to deal with dual-boot. I also using dual-boot(ubunut&windows8). Don't panic, do it

- First, you need to create a backup it's safe for your personnel data or uses a recovery software for backing up your data.
- Create a blank partition and use a bootable pen drive or DVD/CD for installation based on which os you want to install on your computer.
- Start the installation by clicking setup.exe file then click next-next until you get the partition pop-up window, Here you select the empty partition and install on it. Make sure you have remaining partitions safe.
- Windows only supports NTFS partition, Ubuntu supports Ext/sd1 like partitions. Be sure you allocated the correct partition for windows.
- After the installation completed then restart your computer, if you directly getting windows then you should run ubuntu grub menu installation search in google you will find that or Raise a flag to me :)
- If I have any mistakes in my English. Please excuse me.